# How to add a parent div for existing divs

Tags: jquery

I have 2 divs(dynamically created) , I want to add a parent div for these existing divs.

HTML:-

```
<div id="a">div1</div>
<div id="b">div2</div>
```

Output should be like this :-

```
<div id="1">Main Div
<div id="a">div1</div>
<div id="b">div2</div>
</div>
```

Comment: use `.wrapAll()`..[docs](http://api.jquery.com/wrapall/)

Comment: thanks @Kartikeya for the quick help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `.wrapAll()` - which wrap an HTML structure around all elements in the set of matched elements.

```js
$( ".inner" ).wrapAll( "<div id='1' />");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="inner" id="a">div 1</div> 
<div class="inner" id="b">div 2</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

add classes to DOM elements

```
<div id="a" class="inner"></div>
<div id="b" class="inner"></div>
```

Then with jQuery

```
$( ".inner" ).wrapAll( "<div id='1' />");
```

Comment: thanks @Roysh. The main thing is that divs should have something same among them so that we can use that property in jquery to use wrapAll function.